# how to set http headers like X-XSS-Protection in jboss eap 6.4?

Tags: jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

I tried editing the default configuration but i couldnt find the X-XSS-Protection i could find only x-frame options.
Undertow  subsystem is not available in my standalone.xml .

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options.
The first one, is to set this header in a **custom filter** which should be placed in your web application's lib folder. The second option, is to develop a **custom valve** and set this header there.